# disable (read only) a field if within a custom post type name

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have two bidirectional fields '`album_band`' in two different custom post types '`album`' and '`band`'.

This field allow multiple selection and is mandatory in '`album`'

I've been trying to disable or set it as 'read only' this field in one custom type '`band`' (backend side) to avoid empty value in '`album`' but without success.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to create the fields or are you using the built in custom fields system?

Comment: yes i used ACF which doesn't provide any option in that direction

Comment: What do you mean 'bidirectional',  'multiple selection' and 'mandatory'? Is it search? Filter? Show us your code!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I've found a way.
i've managed to find the field name in mysql :

```php
function acf_read_only( $field ) {
    $field['readonly'] = 1;
    $field['disabled'] = true;
return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_5e144c7878e7f', 'acf_read_only');
```

SOLVED !